# Can I get User Storage size/limit by Autodesk Forge Data Management API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

Is There any Data Management api to get storage limit or size per User ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API today to get this information. Note that it also depends if you are 2legged using OSS, or 3legged using one of Autodesk SaaS products such as Fusion 360 Team or BIM 360 Docs for example. With 2legged/OSS, the account is by default set with 500Gb, but this is not a hard limit. If you go over, Autodesk will not stop you doing so, but will contact you to know what are your intents and discuss with you how to extend the storage limit. If you are 3legged, the account manager can determine user right, determine storage for projects, and allocate user rights per project.